# How do I get this weird screw back into this cone?

Tags: screws, chair

I just bought a new armchair, and after screwing its legs in, I hit one of its feet ever so slightly against the floor and poof! Its foot flew right off.

It doesn't look broken, just displaced. I just need to get this round head of the screw back into the cone, but I just can't. Any tips?

#### The chair

[image: The chair]

#### The foot-cone that popped off the screw

[image: The foot-cone that popped off the screw]

Comment: Some analogue to a drift pin unless you have a scaffold builder or an ironworker for a neighbor. My knife has a [marlinspike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlinspike).

Comment: Might want to add a small washer to the screw so you have a greater hold on the foot.  I am guessing the foot came off and not the screw.

Comment: Try different angles of screw and shaft,  you may need to tap it a little.

Comment: Will the cone disassemble?

Comment: Are the feet visible at the bottom in the top picture the same cone piece as shown in the bottom picture?

Comment: I presume that when you got the chair, you got a bag of hardware that had the silver screw pushed through the gold cone. Part of the assembly was to turn the screw into a fitting in the bottom of the leg. Then, when moving the chair, the cone came off, but the screw stayed in place. Is this all correct? Have you tried holding the cone (foot) and turning the screw to simply screw it in?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not understanding what the problem is. "I just need to get this round head of the screw back into the cone, but I just can't." What does that mean?

Comment: Does the black thing we can see through the hole in the cone come off?  If so, remove it and thread the bolt back in through the hole.  You may need to squish the hole a little, since it's obviously hogged out to allow it to come off the bolt.

Comment: why don't you look at one of the other three feet? ... you are missing something

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because furniture repair is off topic here per the [help].

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I took the foot and the screw to a glass repair shop (because I was visiting one anyway), and the handyman there managed to pry open the foot with a flat screw driver, placed the screw back in, and then pressed the hole back in with a drift pin.

Answer (score 1):

What did the manufacturer say when you contacted them to complain about this? I'm sure you are far from the first this has happened to, and they probably have standard advice and/or s standard kit for the repair.

If you're too embarrassed to ask (why?)... This looks like it was assembled by driving the screw from inside the cone, then snapping the plastic foot onto the bottom of the cone. So I'd start by investigating whether the latter can be unsnapped. But it may have been some kind of crimp installation that is hard to undo and redo.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a washer with a hole that the screw just fits through, then adjust, with a hammer & drift, the washer so that it matches the angle of the screw head and cone.

That should stop the screw pulling through the cone.

Edit based on a comment - I would be looking at how to get the "foot part or face" off the cone to access the interior of the cone. It may be that the cone edge has been swagged over or even soldered...

Comment: That sounds like it might help _after_ the OP gets the screw back into the cone, which is what he asked about.

Comment: @Freeman more pictures of the cone may help - perhaps the other face comes off...

Answer (score 0):

Oh no! To fix the issue, try using a rubber mallet or a piece of wood and gently tap the round head of the screw back into the cone. Applying some pressure while tapping might help secure it back in place without causing damage.